# How do I walk up at a T-junction?

Tags: nethack

It is good practice to use walk commands rather than holding direction buttons as much as possible lest you accidentally run into a monster you can't handle and die as a result, a mistake I've made more than once. However, walking in Nethack is... not awesome. This is my situation right now:

```
                                      where I want to go
                                              ↑
                             ###              #        #   ##
                             #                #        #   #
                             #              #########@0#####
                             #              #----------#
                        -----.---------     #|........|#
                        |.............|     #|........-#
                        |.............|     #|........|
                        |.....<.......-######.........|
                        ---------------      ----------
```

If from here I pressed shift-H (run left) I would run all the way to here:

```
                                      where I want to go
                                              ↑
                             ###              #        #   ##
                             #                #        #   #
                             #              ##########0#####
                             #              #----------#
                        -----.---------     #|........|#
                        |.............|     #|........-#
                        |.............|     #|........|
                        |.....<.......-#####@.........|
                        ---------------      ----------
```

If from here I pressed shift-K (run up) I would run up to the boulder and then push it into the intersection.

All other run directions (like the diagonals) don't seem to do anything in my quest to walk up in that T junction. What can I do then?

How can I make walking behave more sensibly?

Comment: For now I'll `5k2lK` but...

Comment: It's like ASCII QWOP

Comment: This has bugged me for ages... even looked into creating a patch for it once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press "g" and then the direction to stop at intersections.  Not SHIFT-direction.

More generally, use the "?" command to read the documentation for various nethack commands, including the differences between SHIFT, "g", "G"/CTRL, and "m" as movement modifiers.

See also http://strategywiki.org/wiki/NetHack/Controls#Advanced_movement

Answer (score 3):

I strongly disagree with the first sentence, but the answer is to use `_` to run to where you want to go.

Comment: Do elaborate, please.

Comment: Seeing as Woobie hasn't elaborated: `_` can be used to go anywhere you can access by walking alone. It corresponds to the click of a mouse when one is enabled. You will try to get there by the most direct path.

Comment: @MarkHurd Thanks for that, although I was rather looking for elaboration on "I strongly disagree with the first sentence" (a sentence I've just revised, may I add.)